# How to stub a function within main in test class (java)

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I'm writing a JUnit test, and I want use mocked objects in the main method.
The main method uses lots of functions. Is there a way to stub one of the functions used in the main method?

Better example:

- main calls a pet manegment class
- managment used a function based of the animal:
  pet.func() where pet is an interface with cat dog and bird implementing it.
  I want to stub the bird.func with returning true for example.
  But I want to test the whole program (public static void main) where i assume that the bird.func() return me true (lets say later in my program im asking if (bird.func()) do something - so I want that something to occur (as if it was a real true value).

Can I stub the return value from pet.func() only in case the object is a bird with Mockito?

Comment: It is hard to judge based on your example. I assume by main you mean a `public static void main(String[] args)` method? If that is the case, then you will have to use Powermock and then use Whitebox in order to inject a mock `object2` inside your `object`, but that will be impossible if `object` only only exists inside your `main()` method. We can't help until you provide more details, show your code please. I think that @michaelbahr is correct in his assertion that you need to break your code into smaller pieces in order to test it. You should follow the tutorial he provided.

Comment: Updated, hope its better now

Answer (score 1):

First question fpr the main method: How many are a lot? In order to improve code quality and testability it is recommended to cut big chunks into smaller pieces.

For your question: Yes it is possible to stub single methods that are being accessed, also through multiple methods. **But** that is bad practice.

In your example not `object2` but `object1` should be mocked. The reason is that when you want to test if `main` works properly, you must be independent from errors in `object1` (if `object1` has errors, that doesn't mean `main` is wrong). Small difference, but huge impact. Thus consider writing two tests:

1. `Main`: mock away `object1.function1()`
2. `Object1.function1()`: mock away `object2.function2()`

Please check [this guide](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html). I made good experience with Mockito.

---

Update to your update:

You are asking for conditional mocking. This highly alerts me, as this makes your tests somewhat unreliable. If you do this, sometimes your tests will use mocked objects, other times not. As a result your tests depend on certain situations that also make your code unmaintainable. Please don't.

Better do it that way: Think about your software and test design. If pet is an interface for animals, all animals must include the interface's definitions and behave somewhat similar.

An example:

```
public interface Pet {
  public String name() {};
}

public class Dog implements Pet {
  public String name() {
    return "Sam";
  }
}

public class Cat implements Pet {
  public String name() {
    return "Emma";
  }
}
```

If you look into the concept of the example:

- name always returns a String
- name always returns one word (no spaces)
- name is always a public method
- specific animals include the interface Pet

You can test those things. Do that first and you develop some testability. However with this example you can ask: *What if I give my elephant a last name?*
Then the test on all pet implementations to check for one name is invalid. Now you either use interface inheritance or write a specific test per animal. And again your code is wonderfully testable without using conditional mocking that you might have forgotten in a year.

Remember to code, as if the guy maintaining you codebase is a serial killer knowing where you live. And the book clean code is very good :)

Comment: Updated, hope its better now :)

Comment: Your question was difficult to understand, but I don't think that it should be downvoted.